# Python: cgi.FieldStorage.getvalue("D1") produces None values to *everything* other than print

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I am trying to make a menu form which uses a dropdown ( hereon called D1 ) to select from several pages. The selected value of D1 is sent to a Python script via HTTP POST (It has to support very old and slow devices, so I can't use JS) which redirects the user to their chosen page.

```
#!C:/python36-32/python
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><head>")
print("")
url = cgi.FieldStorage().getvalue("D1")
#url = url + ".htm"
#print("""<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\";url=\""""+url+"""\" /> """)
print("</head><body>")
print("<center>Redirection</center>")
print(url)
#for i in range len(url):
    #test[i] = url[i]
    print url


print(url[0])
print(url[1])
print(url[2])
#print("""<a href='"""+url+"""'>Click here if you are not redirected.</A>""")
#print(cgi.FieldStorage())
```

As you can see, I have been commenting lines of this code and experimenting to see if I could get it to work, but I've had no luck.

Print treats the output in the "url" variable as a string, but every other command seems to believe it is a NoneType, according to error messages dumped by cgitb. What do I need to do to fix this?

Edit: Here is my HTML code

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>TOMROW</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#6699FF">

<form method="POST" target="_top" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"action="toolbar.py">

    <table style="position=absolute; top=0px; width:100%;" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#000000" border="3">
        <tr>
            <td height="34" width="432"><font face="Courier New">&nbsp;TOMROW</font></td>
            <td height="34" width="168">
    <p align="center">
    <select name="D1">
        <option value="Login">Login</option>
        <option value="policy">Policy</option>
        <option value="links">Links</option>
        <option value="Signup">Sign Up</option>
        <option value="Videos">Videos</option>
        <option value="dload">Download</option>
        <option value="contact">Contact</option>
        <option value="games">Games</option>
        <option value="profile">Your Profile</option>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="B1">
    </p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

My apologies for the poor indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try looking at the developer tools in the browser and checking the HTTP request? Is the POST doing a multipart form or a simple url-based parameter encoding?

I usuarlly try yto debug cgis with a REST addon for the browser and using python built-in http.server with cgi enabled:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

I have done some simple tests with a url-based parameter and everything works as expected. Some additional info would help narrow down the problem.

EDIT:
Using the HTML you provided this works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgitb
import cgi
import os
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
page= form.getvalue("D1")
base_url=os.environ["HTTP_REFERER"]
full_url=os.path.join(base_url,page)
print("Content-Type: text/html")    # HTML is following
print()                             # blank line, end of headers

print("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;{page}.html'>".format(page=full_url))
#print(os.environ)
print("<TITLE>CGI script output</TITLE>")
print("<H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>")
print("This message should never been shown, just a redirect")
```

You do see a flash of the cgi-generated page, maybe try to put a delay and a text indicating you are being redirected.

Comment: The form is using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`